# How to know when 2 parallel threads request is completed in iOS

Tags: ios

for eg. I have two separate requests and both running in different threads then how do I get to know that both are done with their request and completed.

Comment: you can identify the thread property of `var finished: Bool { get }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below implementation , This can help you in detail:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.learn.swift", attributes: .concurrent, target: .main)
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
queue.async (group: group) {
    print("1st Thread")
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
queue.async (group: group) {
    print("2nd Thread")
    group.leave()
}
group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    print("All done")
}
```

Output:

1st Thread

2nd Thread

All done

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dispatch_group` here. Enter into group using `dispatch_enter` and leave by using `dispatch_leave`. Both can notify by `dispatch_group_notify`